# Align icon inside Material UI Button

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, google-material-icons

How to insert an icon centering material ui button?

Piece of Code:

```
 <Button variant="outlined" startIcon={<Add color='primary'/>} style={{ maxWidth: "36px" }} />
```

Expected behavior:

[image]

Current behavior:

[image]

Comment: I don't know material but this could also be entirely the fault of the icon and how the viewbox is setup for it.

Comment: I think it expects a label text but I haven't been able to center the icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this margin is coming from `startIcon` class from material-ui itself. To remove this pass a class in to the `startIcon` in `classes` prop.

```
<Button
    style={{ maxWidth: "36px", minWidth: "36px" }}
    classes={{ startIcon: classes.startICon }}
    variant="outlined"
    startIcon={<Add />}
></Button>
```

And add the class in the useStyles to remove the margin.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  startICon: {
    margin: 0
  }
}));
```

Here is the working demo:
[image: Edit eloquent-shirley-pyt07]

Comment: I wanted the button outline as square instead of rectangle

Comment: for that add a `minWidth` of the same value as of `maxWidth`.. I've updated the answer and demo.... check that